# jQuery mobile-save changes after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am trying to change title of header dynamically by using javascript. I am getting the name of li by id using on click event. The problem is that it shows me the title only for e few sec and then after page is changed title disappear.

```
<div data-role="main" id="page-content-ajax" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
       <li class="li-el"><a href="flow/movements/movements.php" id="Movements">Movements</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#page-content-ajax").on('click', '.li-el', function() {
            var search_r = $('a', this).attr('id');
            $("#title-header").html(search_r); // just to check it works
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: One the page will be changed, the tittle will get changed as you have dynamically added the Tittle! what is the issue in this?

Comment: what jQM version are you using?

Comment: jQM 1.4 - after page is changed I want title to stay there not to disappear

Comment: are you using _internal_ or _external_? Please add more details.

Comment: internal page. I also tried to use pagecontainerload but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen to `pagecontainerbeforetransition` after the *External* page is fully loaded into DOM and created. Also, you need to define a *global variable* which holds new *title*, in able to access it from any function.

```
var title = '';
```

Bind `click` to listview items on `pagecreate` of your home page, i.e. `#HomePage`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#HomePage", function () {
    $("li a").on("click", function () {
        title = $(this).attr("id");
    });
});
```

Update *title* on `pagecontainerbeforetransition`. You can use other events, but the change will occur during showing the page, which may be obvious to user.

`ui.toPage` object holds data of the page which is about to be shown. It's used to find *header* within it to target its' *title*.

Note that you only want to change *title* of pages other than `#HomePage`, hence, I've used `.not()` selector to exclude `#HomePage`.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforetransition", function (e, ui) {
    $(".ui-header .ui-title", $(ui.toPage[0]).not( $("#HomePage") ) ).text(title);
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/r4N5v/)**

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want to stay in that page you need to use AJAX post in your code..[AJAX example](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: I don't want to stay in that page. I want to change page and header title. I am getting the tiltle of the header by li id in first page, after clicking this li it gets id and shows the heder but when go to othe page it disappear.

Comment: your are using that on click event inside the ready function()... once you change the page it will reload again so, on that time it wont get into that click function inside...